# Unable to add a Telegram Bot Library; Beginners fail?

Tags: java, bots, telegram

I've just started to go away from tasks of the university and do my own projects. 
I want to program a Java Telegram Bot to interact with further classes. Unfortunately I'm not able to add the dependency right or it just cant import all of the functions. I tried to follow multiple tutorials but I got errors in either of them. One of the most promising tutorials was the following: https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/wiki/Getting-Started

I followed the instructions (added the library with Maven) and put in the code. After this I imported the needed librarie. However the program isn't able to call the method "execute" and I don't know why. 
I hope I specified the topic detailled enough. 
Thank you in advance.

Main Class:

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContextInitializer;
        import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi;
        import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
        import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.generics.LongPollingBot;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApiContextInitializer.init();

        TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();

        try {
            botsApi.registerBot((LongPollingBot) new Bot());
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Bot Class

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;

public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        // We check if the update has a message and the message has text
        if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
            SendMessage message = new SendMessage() // Create a SendMessage object with mandatory fields
                    .setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId())
                    .setText(update.getMessage().getText());
            try {
                execute(message); // Call method to send the message
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClosing() {

    }
}
```

Error

```
Error:(16, 17) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method execute(org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage)
  location: class Bot
```

Comment: Could you send pom.xml file? or did you use jar?

Comment: I used a jar I guess. Because I just started programming and wasn't able to solve the problem the project is not longer in progress. I don't know when I will return to it.

Answer (score 1):

You must set in the getters botToken and botUsername the token and username of bot.

```
return "<token>";

return "<username_of_bot>";
```

at least minimum the token.

Answer (score 0):

in the POM.xml file I added the follow dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.telegram/telegrambots -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
    <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
    <version>4.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

You can also download directly the jar.
You must create and define the bot with BotFather, use a username, take the token and create the class that extends **TelegramLongPollingBot**.

Your problem is on the token and username that return always null. You must return the  configuration created with BothFather.